# Grunt error while watching SCSS files, aborting task

Tags: sass, gruntjs

I'm setting up Grunt on a project for the first time and am having trouble trying to get it to watch my Sass files. I have everything I need installed and watch is working properly. But when I make changes in my .scss file, I get the following error message in my terminal:

```
File "css/global.scss" changed.
Running "sass:style" (sass) task
Verifying property sass.style exists in config...ERROR
Unable to process task.
Warning: Required config property "sass.style" missing. Use --force to continue.
Aborted due to warnings.
```

I can't figure out where the sass.style property it's referencing is and/or how to tell it to look for a different property.

My file structure looks like this:

```
Gruntfile.js
package.json
index.html
css/ --- build/ --- global.css
     --- global.scss
js/  --- build/ --- global.min.js
     --- global.js
node_modules/
```

My Gruntfile looks like this:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

grunt.initConfig({
pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
uglify: {
  options: { },
  build: {
    src: ['js/libs/*.js','js/global.js'],
    dest: 'js/build/global.min.js'
  }
},

sass: {
    dist: {
      options: {
        style: 'compressed'
      },
      files: {
        'css/build/global.css':'css/global.scss'
      }
    }
  },

watch: {
 js: {
   files: ['js/*.js'],
   tasks: ['uglify:js'],
   options: {
     livereload: true,
   }
 },
 css: {
   files: ['**/*.scss'],
   tasks: ['sass'],
   options: {
     livereload: true,
   }
 }
},

serve: {
 options: {
     port: 9000
 }
}

});

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-serve');

grunt.registerTask('default', ['uglify','sass','watch', 'serve']);

};
```

Comment: It's thinking `style` is a task, which seems odd from what I see in your config. What is the output if you run the sass task directly with the verbose flag (`grunt sass --verbose`)?

Comment: It completes without error when I run that task you've suggested.

Comment: Which version of grunt-contrib-watch are you running?

Comment: @KyleRobinsonYoung 0.6.1

Comment: @DanielleWebb Hmm same version I tried and could not reproduce by copying the above example gruntfile. Sorry, I don't have any idea where `sass:style` is coming from.

Comment: @KyleRobinsonYoung for some reason, it now seems to be working. Thanks for your efforts!